# Obtaining next set of results

Tags: here-api

I've searched around but cannot seem to find the answer to this, I need to access more pages worth of results from a places search. I noticed in the JSON response there is a next field with a URL that, when clicked in the browser, calls a further 20 results. However I haven't been able to access this field in my C# application. Below is the JSON response (text format).

```
{
results: {next:https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search;context=Zmxv...
items: [ 
{ The Botanist }
{ Alexanders Jazz Theatre Bar }
{ The Architect }
{ 1539 Restaurant & Bar }
{ Barlounge Chester }
{ Meze }
{ Hanky Panky Pancakes }
{ The Slowboat }
{ The Moorings }
{ Missoula }
{ Istanbul BBQ }
{ Chip-O-Dee }
{ The Flower Cup }
{ Mama K's Burritos }
{ The Stage Door Cafe Chester }
{ Cinderbox Coffee }
{ Wok&Go }
{ Covino }
{ Urbano 32 }
{ Beatons Tearooms }
]
}
search: {
context: { urn:nlp-types:place }
supportsPanning:true
ranking:category-recommendations
}
}
```

And my C# classes used to access the fields, the next string just returns null:

```
[System.Serializable]
    public class Response
    {
        public results results;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class results
    {
        public string next;
        public string previous;
        public items[] items;
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Places API is built from a consumer perspective and restricted only to return the first 100(relevant) POIs around a location. There is no provision to get all the POIs as of today.

Comment: Ah right! Thank you for that. It looks like it's accessible via the response example on the website, I spent hours scratching my head at why I couldn't access it! Ha.